# Chat word filter, regex replacing spaces

Tags: regex, filter, chat

I am developing a bad word filter for a chat, but I'm having problems with sentences, the regex is working fine but when I write a sentence it replaces spaces with *.

Example:

Genius is a bad word.

User write:

I'm a Genius ok?

Result:

```
Should be:

I'm a ****** ok?

But the result is:

I'm*a********ok?

Regex is replacing spaces.
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: What I get is this: `Hi *`, so I do not know how you are getting the multiple `*`. Also, it might be a good idea to provide an example which some people might not consider offensive.

Comment: Now you have removed your regex. Regular expressions do *not* replace spaces out of the blue. Please provide a SSCCE as described here: http://www.sscce.org/